# raspberry pi rgb-led-matrix 32x16

Tags: raspberry-pi

подключил напрямую по [туториалу](https://learn.adafruit.com/connecting-a-16x32-rgb-led-matrix-panel-to-a-raspberry-pi2) к gpio [led матрицу](https://p10.ru/led-moduli/svetodiodnye-moduli-dlja-led-jekranov/svetodiodnyj-modul-q10-polnocvetnyj-smd-320x160-6000-qiangli), но вместо изображения засвечиваются рандомные пиксели. Также заметил странность hub75 имеет странные обозначения "S","L" и "CS" вместо привычных LAT и CLK. Может кто сталкивался и знает как решить проблему?

Comment: У Распберри же есть отдельный слот  для подключения матрицы. Только что посмотрел: разъём "Display"и модуль нужен соответствующий. Оговорюсь, что у меня Raspberry Pi 2 и на ней есть HDMI выход.
И ещё: шумы в проводниках никто не отменял.

Comment: CS - Chip Select, выбор чипа. Что такое S и L следует читать в мануале к устройству. Предполагаю, что S - Shift, L - Load.

Comment: Получается управлять этой матрицей как в туториале не получится?

Comment: Ссылка не работает. Ничего не могу утверждать. GPIO сложен сам по себе.

Comment: это ссылка на стандаpтный урок от adafruit